# Are any relation between 100% disk usage and reallocated sector count and current pending sector count?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hardware-failure, disk-space

I am suffering from 100% disk usage while not using anything on my hp pc. I run crystal disk info and the health status was caution, also I observed yellow sign beside reallocated sector count and current pending sector count, is there a relation between them and high disk usage and how can I fix this issue on my hard drive ?

Comment: Yes there is probably a connection. Your disk is dying. Back it up while you still can.

Answer (score 0):

A rising reallocated sector count is correlated with a premature hard drive death.
You can fix the issue by replacing the drive.

High disk usage caused by a lack of RAM that causes swapping in and out could as well accelerate disk degradation.

Answer (score 0):

Windows constantly writes and reads tiny little pieces of information to your hard drive while your computer is on and not doing anything. Your drive is in trouble and is trying its hardest, but failing with high disk usage as a symptom. First priority is to stop windows from reading and writing to that failing drive. Take your hard drive out of your PC. This will prevent the Windows read/writes.

Plug your hdd into another working computer with Windows. This can be accomplished by connecting the drive directly on the inside of another computer with sata cables (you need sata power cables and sata cables) or via USB in a HDD external enclosure (you gotta buy an enclosure).

Once that drive is detected it should act just like a USB drive and greatly reduce those read/writes. Now you should be able to recover your files quickly and much more safely.